# How to include this value in JavaScript code or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

HI I want to include this value `top-ad` in JavaScript or jQuery code

```
<b:switch var='data:link.name'><b:case value='top-ad'/></b:switch>
```

I tried this code but it didn't work

```
$("top-ad").appendTo("div")
```

Comment: What is that top bit? It isn't HTML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean you want this:

jQuery:

```
$("div").val('top-ad')
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector("div").value = "top-ad";
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre, welcome to StackOverflow. It is better if you explain a little your answer to the op, instead of simply giving the answer

Comment: @Alexandre Thank you my friend I appreciate your help